# Posting multiple parameters via javascript from view MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to save any changes made in the textbox field instantaneously to my database, I have the javascript to pass back the changed value to the controller, however I am not aware how pass the unique id with this to save the changed value against. 

 Below is my view passing the price back to the script, how can I pass the part id with this?

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.partid, new { id = "partCode"})
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => item.partdesc)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.price, new { id = "priceTextBox", @class = "mytext rightJustified" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#priceTextBox').change(function () {
        var changedText = $(this).val();
        var partsJava = $("#partCode").val();
        
            //Post the content of your Textbox to your "YourAction" action in "YourController"
        $.post('@Url.Action("EnterNewSpecialPrice2", "SpecialPrices")', { "ChangedText": changedText, "PassPartCode": partsJava }, function (data) { });
            });
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class to hold both pieces of information that matches the Json object you have created in your script:

```
 public class PartInputModel{

    public string ChangedText {get;set;}
    public string PassPartCode {get;set;}

 }
```

Note the properties above must match the ones you have defined here:

```
{ ChangedText: changedText, PassPartCode: partsJava }
```

Also note you must remove the double quotes around the ChangedText and PassPartCode definition when creating the JSON structure as those are not required.

Change your controller action to receive this object and let the model binding do the work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnterNewSpecialPrice2(PartInputModel inputModel)   {
        // inputModel will have your two pieces of data 

    }
```

A better mechanism for storing and retrieving the id is to attach it as a data tag to the markup for the Text Box by adding a data-id tag:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.price, new { id = "", @class = "priceTextBox mytext rightJustified", data_id="item.partid" })
```

Then change your script to read this:

```
var partsJava = $(this).data('id');
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is very easy to pass additional parameters by simply expanding your JSON structure and adding a matching property to the `PartInputModel` class.

Comment: Hi thanks @CSL, I have followed your approach and i'm still only receiving the value for the ChangedText, the PassPartCode is still returning null. Am I correctly referencing the partid?

Comment: @cg91 See my edits above add a data tag to the text box markup and then change the script slightly to read this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hey - I have upvoted you - your answer is good. I would have just pointed the OP in the direction of your answer other than the fact he has already changed the structure to use a class - so it may have been confusing for them to switch back to your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You generating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes and selectors such as `var partsJava = $("#partCode").val();` will only ever get the value of the first element with `id="partCode"`. In anycase, it would be undefined since `DisplayFor()` does not generate a element (only text) and it has `id` attribute or `value` attribute. Change your loop to

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.partid)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.partdesc)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.price, new { id = "", @class = "priceTextBox mytext rightJustified", data_id="item.partid" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and then modify the script to

```
$('.priceTextBox').change(function () {
    var changedText = $(this).val();
    var partsJava = $(this).data('id');
    $.post('@Url.Action("EnterNewSpecialPrice2", "SpecialPrices")', { "ChangedText": changedText, "PassPartCode": partsJava }, function (data) { });
    });
});
```

Note the `new { id="" }` remove the `id` attribute so you do not get invalid html.

This of course assumes you have a method

```
public ActionResult EnterNewSpecialPrice2(string ChangedText, string PassPartCode)
```

in `SpecialPricesController` (although `PassPartCode` may be `int`?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I used a combination of both your answers to help me, i'm giving CSL the top answer as he answered first, I have upvoted your reply